# Simplifying this Boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

How do you simplify this expression?

$$\lnot[\lnot[(P \lor Q) \land R] \lor \lnot Q] \equiv Q \land R$$

I understand the laws used but still not getting the exact answer.
I would appreciate if someone solved this for me.

Comment: In the future, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions (I've cleaned up your post for you this time).  Also, it is really helpful if you state the question in the actual body, in addition to in the title.  Someone should be able to understand your question without having to read the title.

Comment: What does it mean $A\lor \land B$?

Comment: @caverac that was a typo introduced in the MathJax edit, so I've fixed it according to the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\lnot[\lnot[(P\lor Q)\land R]\lor \lnot Q] &=& [(P\lor Q)\land R] \land Q \\
&=&
[(P\land R)\lor (Q\land R)] \land Q \\
&=& (P\land R\land Q) \lor (Q\land R) \\
&=& (P\land A) \lor A ~~~\mbox{where}~~~ A = Q\land R\\
&=& A = Q \land R
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Equality 1: negation and De Morgan's Law.

Equality 2: distributive law.

Equality 3: distributive law.

Equality 4: re-labeling.

Equality 5: ??

Comment: @JesterTran It's called the *redundancy law*